# Kotlin | How can i use a variable in a fragment from another fragment?

Tags: kotlin, variables, android-fragments

How can i use a variable in a fragment from another fragment in Kotlin?

I got in Fragment 1 called "MainFragment":

```
var currentvalue = 0
```

And in Fragment 2 i want to change this var to "10" so i tried:

```
    button.setOnClickListener() {

        val fm = fragmentManager
        (fm!!.findFragmentById(R.id.mainFragment) as MainFragment?)?.currentvalue = 10

    }
```

But it doesnt work for me (no errors - but the "currentvalue" doesn't change in "Fragment 1").

Answer (score 1):

If **Fragment 2** is your `MainFragment`, and from there you want to set `currentValue` in some *other* fragment, you need to find that *other* fragment in the fragment manager. So use `R.id.fragment1` (or whatever it's called) in your lookup

That requires your **Fragment 1** to be present in the fragment manager, either in the layout or added yourself with a fragment transaction. If you're adding and removing fragments, and you want one to effect a change in another when it gets loaded, you need some way of passing data, or storing and retrieving it.

[Here's the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) about it - the first example is using `ViewModel`s as a data store outside of the fragments, so each one can update to the current data when it's created. There are some more methods at the bottom. Other ways are to create your own storage object in a file, like

```
object Stuff {
    var currentValue = 0
}
```

and that acts as a singleton object in your app - it's not ideal but it can work fine. Or you could use `SharedPreferences` to store a value with a key, and retrieve the current value when the fragment loads - this has the benefit of persisting the data between app sessions too